# How to reorder the text blocks of a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, text-files

I have a text file like this:

```
Label: A

Text1

Text2

Label: B

Text3

Text4

Label: C

Text5

Text6
```

I would like to reorder the blocks of text in the inverse order, maintaining the original order within the blocks. Like this:

```
Label: C

Text5

Text6

Label: B

Text3

Text4

Label: A

Text1

Text2
```

The line with `Label` always contains the same text, I'm adding here the letters for a better explanation. Also, the `Label` is always at the same position and uses a full line.

The only constrains are: Python 3.6 and no external modules. I can load the full file in memory, so no need for read the file line by line if you don't want.

I know how to find the lines with the `Label` but I don't know how to select the block of text to change the order. Any idea?.

Comment: read the file: find a lable, create a dict-entry with label as key, add all the text untile next label as value. Repeat. Either use an OrderedDict or create a small lists that records the order of the labels. Reverse the list or reverse the Ordered dict keys and write them again.

Comment: I'd write an iterator that groups the file into chunks of lines breaking on each one that starts with `Label:`, then just reverse it and output. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, you gave me some ideas. Sincerely, I didn't think in to use a dict which is the easier for me. 

Answer (score 1):

For this type of work the basic pattern is to define a function that knows how to yield the meaningful units (the blocks or sections of the file that you care about):

```
import sys

def main(file_path):
    blocks = list(read_blocks(file_path))
    for block in reversed(blocks):
        for line in block:
            print(line, end = '')

def read_blocks(file_path):
    block = []
    with open(file_path) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            if line.startswith('Label: '):
                if block:
                    yield block
                block = []
            block.append(line)
    # A common bug is to forget the last block.
    if block:
        yield block

main(sys.argv[1])
```